# Python: Qt4: 'QListView' object has no attribute 'addColumn'

Tags: python, pyqt4, qlistview

For some weird reason this `QListView` object doesn't have `addColumn` attribute. Could you explain what I'm doing wrong here ?

```
self.pointListBox = QtGui.QListView(self)

self.pointListBox.addColumn("test")
self.pointListBox.addColumn("another")

self.pointLabelBox.QListViewItem(QString("derp"))
```

Eventually, I'm trying to get a simple `QListView` working exactly similar to this one. In Python!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to functionality of a QListView from the older Qt3, which did have the `addColumn()` method: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/3.3/qlistview.html

But you are using Qt4 / PyQt4, which is not the same API: http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qlistview.html

I recommend you find an updated tutorial/guide to work from or pick up a [modern PyQt4 book](http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html).

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking at isn't a `QListView` object. That's a `QTreeWidget`.

To add a new "column", you need to modify the header using `QTreeWidget.setHeader()`. Top-level items are added using `QTreeWidget.addTopLevelItem()`.

You can find Qt's documentation for this element here: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtreewidget.html

Comment: In the tutorial in the link below they got this using QListView... Although I guess it doesn't matter how to get there... I'm going to try it out with QTreeWidget.  http://www.digitalfanatics.org/projects/qt_tutorial/chapter13.html

Comment: @Kiarash: That tutorial seems to have been written for Qt3. The references are not valid for Qt4. QListView no longer has those same methods.

Comment: Thanks jdi.   Blender, I can change the top level header using QTreeWidget.setHeader() but not the columns. Is there any way to add columns ?

Comment: You use `addTopLevelItem` to add rows.